# Take errors on data into account when using lmfit

Tags: python, curve-fitting, lmfit

I am trying to fit a curve to some data (the model would be 3 Gaussians plus background). The data is at the bottom of this post (not sure how to attach it), and the columns are (x, y, err_y), with err_y being the square root of y. Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from lmfit.models import GaussianModel, LinearModel

data = np.loadtxt("data.txt")
x = data[:,0]
y = data[:,1]
err = data[:,2]

background = LinearModel(prefix='line1_')
pars = background.guess(y,x=x)

peak1 = GaussianModel(prefix='g1_')
pars.update(peak1.make_params())

pars['g1_center'].set(9200, min=9000, max=10000)
pars['g1_sigma'].set(300, min=100, max=700)

peak2 = GaussianModel(prefix='g2_')
pars.update(peak2.make_params())

pars['g2_center'].set(10500, min=10000, max=11000)
pars['g2_sigma'].set(300, min=100, max=700)

peak3 = GaussianModel(prefix='g3_')
pars.update(peak3.make_params())

pars['g3_center'].set(13000, min=12000, max=14000)
pars['g3_sigma'].set(300, min=100, max=700)

model =  peak1 + peak2 + peak3 + background
weight = 1/err**2/np.sum(1/err**2)

out = model.fit(y, pars, x=x)#, weights = weight)

print(out.fit_report(min_correl=0.1))

plt.errorbar(x,y,err, fmt="b.")
plt.plot(x, out.best_fit, 'r-')
plt.show()
```

If for the fit I use this: `out = model.fit(y, pars, x=x)`, so without using the errors on the y, I get these values for the parameters (I post just mu and sigma here):

```
mu_1 =  9359.791209085675  +/-  5.509374978209427
sigma_1 =  348.86904194695535  +/-  6.18259118657156
mu_2 =  10522.11131671362  +/-  3.288369260611981
sigma_2 =  243.53890651538205  +/-  3.43678656935972
mu_3 =  13098.71965433265  +/-  4.737992827401577
sigma_3 =  324.0256260123612  +/-  5.054936854719746
```

and this is the fit itself:

[image]

If I want to take into account the errors: `out = model.fit(y, pars, x=x, weights = weight)` (the weight are the inverse of the squares of the errors, as the formula for the least-square fit is sum{1/sigma^2*(y_data-y_pred)^2}, right?) I get these numbers:

```
mu_1 =  9979.839872555114  +/-  12.208145818989209
sigma_1 =  296.96756984463025  +/-  30.943773101487675
mu_2 =  10000.004017862604  +/-  14.082237906871443
sigma_2 =  424.30653650290424  +/-  22.751836748822086
mu_3 =  13103.00302126283  +/-  10.795125319448884
sigma_3 =  328.0535307828716  +/-  8.157121458823843
```

and this fit:

[image]

Not only the fit looks bad, but the printed parameters are not even what the figure shows (the center of the first peak is for sure smaller than 9980). Can someone tell me what is going on? Am I using the weights parameter the way it is supposed to be used? Why does the fit looks so bad now? Why are the printed parameters wrong? And how can I fix it? Thank you!

```
7.000000000000000000e+03 6.000000002025068113e+00 2.449489743196543223e+00
7.030000000000000000e+03 3.000000004315769964e+00 1.732050808814732834e+00
7.060000000000000000e+03 4.000000006197925728e+00 2.000000001549481432e+00
7.090000000000000000e+03 4.000000012537167748e+00 2.000000003134291937e+00
7.120000000000000000e+03 3.000000025319851993e+00 1.732050814878088874e+00
7.150000000000000000e+03 6.000000048240711870e+00 2.449489752630272132e+00
7.180000000000000000e+03 3.000000088846842772e+00 1.732050833216751462e+00
7.210000000000000000e+03 3.000000108732610027e+00 1.732050838957277739e+00
7.240000000000000000e+03 5.000000229801089269e+00 2.236068028884874881e+00
7.270000000000000000e+03 3.000000458168750495e+00 1.732050939830797942e+00
7.300000000000000000e+03 4.000000648255159774e+00 2.000000162063783282e+00
7.330000000000000000e+03 6.000001048612724652e+00 2.449489956830344983e+00
7.360000000000000000e+03 3.000001893300531908e+00 1.732051354117577047e+00
7.390000000000000000e+03 4.000003209987961661e+00 2.000000802496829433e+00
7.420000000000000000e+03 3.000005614832372380e+00 1.732052428430609803e+00
7.450000000000000000e+03 6.000007610745573317e+00 2.449491296319620037e+00
7.480000000000000000e+03 6.000016587004323831e+00 2.449493128588917656e+00
7.510000000000000000e+03 3.000023522142809096e+00 1.732057597813308591e+00
7.540000000000000000e+03 3.000042277494411991e+00 1.732063011987269530e+00
7.570000000000000000e+03 3.000061265618661821e+00 1.732068493339296911e+00
7.600000000000000000e+03 5.000096923842210828e+00 2.236089650224742265e+00
7.630000000000000000e+03 3.000149325177520421e+00 1.732093913498202964e+00
7.660000000000000000e+03 6.000267595088342176e+00 2.449544364792836770e+00
7.690000000000000000e+03 5.000335283249713214e+00 2.236142947856802898e+00
7.720000000000000000e+03 5.000501755853099084e+00 2.236180170704744175e+00
7.750000000000000000e+03 6.000910405671596060e+00 2.449675571513827421e+00
7.780000000000000000e+03 5.001208459077773227e+00 2.236338180838885137e+00
7.810000000000000000e+03 3.001721957803603846e+00 1.732547822659912473e+00
7.840000000000000000e+03 6.002920840865169083e+00 2.450085884385518664e+00
7.870000000000000000e+03 6.003907394531575292e+00 2.450287206539587537e+00
7.900000000000000000e+03 6.006637148541026150e+00 2.450844170595312566e+00
7.930000000000000000e+03 4.008694833793983392e+00 2.002172528478498581e+00
7.960000000000000000e+03 4.014127013944937872e+00 2.003528640660007465e+00
7.990000000000000000e+03 3.019275529910475431e+00 1.737606264350608054e+00
8.020000000000000000e+03 5.025018883638190381e+00 2.241655389135045251e+00
8.050000000000000000e+03 6.042115933362167013e+00 2.458071588331423474e+00
8.080000000000000000e+03 5.053108931155777306e+00 2.247912127098338431e+00
8.110000000000000000e+03 3.078002686523067410e+00 1.754423747708365733e+00
8.140000000000000000e+03 5.081783275465313388e+00 2.254281099478348871e+00
8.170000000000000000e+03 3.130838624775529766e+00 1.769417594796527826e+00
8.200000000000000000e+03 4.168204056392665890e+00 2.041617999624970370e+00
8.230000000000000000e+03 3.239172982051586214e+00 1.799770258130627631e+00
8.260000000000000000e+03 6.312598138475916443e+00 2.512488435490980887e+00
8.290000000000000000e+03 4.381843223025915890e+00 2.093285270340838000e+00
8.320000000000000000e+03 4.568003879206393947e+00 2.137288908689322309e+00
8.350000000000000000e+03 4.746035881728059458e+00 2.178539850846906045e+00
8.380000000000000000e+03 5.792806639069331354e+00 2.406825012141375453e+00
8.410000000000000000e+03 7.371239187625640454e+00 2.715002612821144190e+00
8.440000000000000000e+03 4.637320788016664252e+00 2.153443936585455631e+00
8.470000000000000000e+03 7.249356649863059943e+00 2.692462933795572333e+00
8.500000000000000000e+03 5.487189433006939510e+00 2.342475065610504892e+00
8.530000000000000000e+03 7.645865265607722172e+00 2.765115777975259093e+00
8.560000000000000000e+03 9.559755680159868874e+00 3.091885457153914274e+00
8.590000000000000000e+03 9.548054089404699241e+00 3.089992571092153639e+00
8.620000000000000000e+03 8.435550600857649073e+00 2.904401935142181479e+00
8.650000000000000000e+03 1.210847833505386895e+01 3.479723887760905132e+00
8.680000000000000000e+03 1.134957378865382083e+01 3.368912849667355491e+00
8.710000000000000000e+03 1.268204245376933947e+01 3.561185540486389911e+00
8.740000000000000000e+03 1.656698363272819563e+01 4.070255966487635213e+00
8.770000000000000000e+03 1.888757726679436999e+01 4.345984038948413897e+00
8.800000000000000000e+03 1.935244284918934099e+01 4.399141149041406074e+00
8.830000000000000000e+03 2.187787847133657593e+01 4.677379444874723013e+00
8.860000000000000000e+03 2.226085259387548732e+01 4.718140798436974315e+00
8.890000000000000000e+03 2.932576669517617418e+01 5.415327016457655240e+00
8.920000000000000000e+03 3.262480898198393930e+01 5.711813108110588288e+00
8.950000000000000000e+03 3.542567665213159955e+01 5.951947299172902106e+00
8.980000000000000000e+03 4.050199512350188513e+01 6.364117780454875195e+00
9.010000000000000000e+03 3.905862845818743523e+01 6.249690268980330643e+00
9.040000000000000000e+03 4.468898696059456910e+01 6.684982195981868713e+00
9.070000000000000000e+03 4.831501050751828785e+01 6.950899978241543486e+00
9.100000000000000000e+03 4.420713286272618348e+01 6.648844475751119809e+00
9.130000000000000000e+03 5.261355553413167740e+01 7.253520216703864598e+00
9.160000000000000000e+03 5.966281794561411544e+01 7.724171019961566742e+00
9.190000000000000000e+03 5.438586594465710533e+01 7.374677345122097272e+00
9.220000000000000000e+03 6.577092368455110716e+01 8.109927477144978525e+00
9.250000000000000000e+03 5.921666724506510349e+01 7.695236659457920680e+00
9.280000000000000000e+03 5.277669080499678245e+01 7.264756761585124067e+00
9.310000000000000000e+03 6.762079443092432030e+01 8.223186391595676881e+00
9.340000000000000000e+03 6.059274352790759366e+01 7.784134089794933153e+00
9.370000000000000000e+03 5.576251175641795754e+01 7.467430063711206323e+00
9.400000000000000000e+03 5.707908122185955335e+01 7.555069901851309666e+00
9.430000000000000000e+03 6.151773978576188995e+01 7.843324536557306992e+00
9.460000000000000000e+03 7.048630726012294190e+01 8.395612381483731568e+00
9.490000000000000000e+03 6.291014290070520332e+01 7.931591448171369407e+00
9.520000000000000000e+03 4.734757195983997491e+01 6.880957197936925063e+00
9.550000000000000000e+03 6.500114987778607656e+01 8.062329060376168144e+00
9.580000000000000000e+03 4.753922632576585272e+01 6.894869565536816403e+00
9.610000000000000000e+03 5.385103353414591254e+01 7.338326344211322017e+00
9.640000000000000000e+03 4.831960571751936584e+01 6.951230518226205746e+00
9.670000000000000000e+03 4.238053790545737343e+01 6.510033633204775683e+00
9.700000000000000000e+03 4.372009186278721415e+01 6.612117048479043468e+00
9.730000000000000000e+03 4.080790659420628685e+01 6.388106651755768084e+00
9.760000000000000000e+03 3.812578076631131552e+01 6.174607741898372026e+00
9.790000000000000000e+03 2.937316102002224838e+01 5.419701192872375728e+00
9.820000000000000000e+03 2.708505517917794947e+01 5.204330425633824753e+00
9.850000000000000000e+03 2.849714610371207968e+01 5.338271827446789075e+00
9.880000000000000000e+03 2.596446279950968261e+01 5.095533612832878312e+00
9.910000000000000000e+03 2.178890113972214237e+01 4.667858303303790812e+00
9.940000000000000000e+03 2.589850995959588786e+01 5.089057865616767096e+00
9.970000000000000000e+03 2.234950984902263826e+01 4.727526821607957785e+00
1.000000000000000000e+04 2.434453817935357733e+01 4.934018461594320115e+00
1.003000000000000000e+04 2.338718628196880545e+01 4.836030012517375631e+00
1.006000000000000000e+04 2.455987922924956024e+01 4.955792492553492856e+00
1.009000000000000000e+04 3.162049009036499214e+01 5.623209945428411238e+00
1.012000000000000000e+04 3.033947851189581613e+01 5.508128403722612809e+00
1.015000000000000000e+04 3.611465972648677791e+01 6.009547381166636448e+00
1.018000000000000000e+04 3.492729712698738354e+01 5.909932074650891209e+00
1.021000000000000000e+04 4.178027939963527615e+01 6.463766657269991001e+00
1.024000000000000000e+04 5.205483113215301216e+01 7.214903404214987326e+00
1.027000000000000000e+04 5.783883322438956753e+01 7.605184627896259819e+00
1.030000000000000000e+04 6.340032272267990265e+01 7.962431960317142732e+00
1.033000000000000000e+04 6.853862629802827655e+01 8.278805849760475510e+00
1.036000000000000000e+04 6.517169419377570705e+01 8.072898747895683513e+00
1.039000000000000000e+04 9.098971124158184409e+01 9.538852721453553229e+00
1.042000000000000000e+04 7.193155636898768535e+01 8.481247335680505373e+00
1.045000000000000000e+04 7.274302186573994788e+01 8.528951979331338862e+00
1.048000000000000000e+04 9.577257663558641809e+01 9.786346439585429380e+00
1.051000000000000000e+04 8.710469426409028415e+01 9.332989567340696624e+00
1.054000000000000000e+04 8.954011000372375406e+01 9.462563606323804777e+00
1.057000000000000000e+04 8.687481152507338322e+01 9.320665830565614485e+00
1.060000000000000000e+04 7.763568480759039403e+01 8.811111439971146098e+00
1.063000000000000000e+04 8.629670469860160154e+01 9.289601966639992270e+00
1.066000000000000000e+04 6.783521222485546787e+01 8.236213464017033914e+00
1.069000000000000000e+04 7.189779921263537688e+01 8.479256996496530974e+00
1.072000000000000000e+04 6.863365639941915219e+01 8.284543222134770346e+00
1.075000000000000000e+04 5.844622857659397397e+01 7.645013314350340039e+00
1.078000000000000000e+04 5.189207520617652847e+01 7.203615426032717650e+00
1.081000000000000000e+04 5.096385133602026229e+01 7.138897067196042556e+00
1.084000000000000000e+04 3.763259313002745898e+01 6.134540987720878746e+00
1.087000000000000000e+04 3.311264995306950709e+01 5.754359213072252288e+00
1.090000000000000000e+04 2.841510790948335341e+01 5.330582323675655765e+00
1.093000000000000000e+04 2.392134835950111693e+01 4.890945548613387928e+00
1.096000000000000000e+04 1.906003747919087488e+01 4.365780282972434811e+00
1.099000000000000000e+04 1.770028480772651491e+01 4.207170641622052898e+00
1.102000000000000000e+04 1.358324428649685878e+01 3.685545317384777420e+00
1.105000000000000000e+04 1.288071825660460412e+01 3.588971754779438861e+00
1.108000000000000000e+04 1.095847215257629870e+01 3.310358311811018694e+00
1.111000000000000000e+04 7.645146244414394943e+00 2.764985758446939279e+00
1.114000000000000000e+04 6.367768732538436893e+00 2.523443823931580177e+00
1.117000000000000000e+04 8.078065785661223686e+00 2.842193833231861699e+00
1.120000000000000000e+04 6.488639333507772555e+00 2.547280772413550221e+00
1.123000000000000000e+04 4.026936461165597336e+00 2.006722816226893968e+00
1.126000000000000000e+04 3.656803118754337945e+00 1.912276946144134682e+00
1.129000000000000000e+04 5.516244046295580183e+00 2.348668568848227167e+00
1.132000000000000000e+04 5.331021857086072124e+00 2.308900573235251219e+00
1.135000000000000000e+04 5.194472716769368503e+00 2.279138590952592303e+00
1.138000000000000000e+04 6.143443503613321255e+00 2.478597083757931419e+00
1.141000000000000000e+04 6.078965652996855873e+00 2.465555850715383190e+00
1.144000000000000000e+04 5.055868990941812413e+00 2.248525959588150158e+00
1.147000000000000000e+04 6.035914502389383429e+00 2.456809822185955117e+00
1.150000000000000000e+04 3.015070267504368573e+00 1.736395769260098421e+00
1.153000000000000000e+04 5.012436511453791432e+00 2.238847138920786684e+00
1.156000000000000000e+04 6.007104976078236014e+00 2.450939610859116158e+00
1.159000000000000000e+04 3.005141736793108809e+00 1.733534463687731009e+00
1.162000000000000000e+04 5.003604639599076087e+00 2.236873854198996980e+00
1.165000000000000000e+04 6.002914461088206366e+00 2.450084582435513969e+00
1.168000000000000000e+04 3.003617523082932728e+00 1.733094781909787052e+00
1.171000000000000000e+04 6.004421178413331894e+00 2.450392045859872692e+00
1.174000000000000000e+04 5.008949419209775655e+00 2.238068233814549224e+00
1.177000000000000000e+04 3.009692818601786612e+00 1.734846626823762339e+00
1.180000000000000000e+04 6.011869634283223185e+00 2.451911424640625725e+00
1.183000000000000000e+04 5.025074764614068101e+00 2.241667853321287041e+00
1.186000000000000000e+04 6.028860455009264818e+00 2.455373791301288744e+00
1.189000000000000000e+04 5.051196683529439291e+00 2.247486748243343602e+00
1.192000000000000000e+04 4.080472044548372423e+00 2.020017832730288454e+00
1.195000000000000000e+04 4.099334156786992978e+00 2.024681248193648919e+00
1.198000000000000000e+04 6.141484470682121000e+00 2.478201862375646325e+00
1.201000000000000000e+04 5.194815473399751582e+00 2.279213784049173519e+00
1.204000000000000000e+04 3.243452402190742490e+00 1.800958745277287720e+00
1.207000000000000000e+04 5.374471441140894257e+00 2.318290629136237957e+00
1.210000000000000000e+04 3.414532518726645982e+00 1.847845371974247808e+00
1.213000000000000000e+04 5.556250452212307955e+00 2.357170009187353532e+00
1.216000000000000000e+04 5.749742812091656496e+00 2.397862133670669582e+00
1.219000000000000000e+04 7.292661906110824432e+00 2.700492900585155009e+00
1.222000000000000000e+04 6.380440371069494354e+00 2.525953358846812602e+00
1.225000000000000000e+04 6.756238869580919015e+00 2.599276605053975064e+00
1.228000000000000000e+04 5.380341588954090426e+00 2.319556334507547835e+00
1.231000000000000000e+04 8.968172780554571233e+00 2.994690765430476187e+00
1.234000000000000000e+04 7.221677075806642421e+00 2.687317821882377000e+00
1.237000000000000000e+04 7.681878795823965156e+00 2.771620247404749549e+00
1.240000000000000000e+04 1.143868965573109975e+01 3.382113193808140572e+00
1.243000000000000000e+04 1.033814312045844375e+01 3.215298294164702142e+00
1.246000000000000000e+04 1.011304872103110242e+01 3.180101998526321250e+00
1.249000000000000000e+04 1.610857232051627363e+01 4.013548594512874601e+00
1.252000000000000000e+04 1.861575944099877233e+01 4.314598410165049636e+00
1.255000000000000000e+04 1.917058150777199188e+01 4.378422262387672959e+00
1.258000000000000000e+04 2.097495971145594851e+01 4.579842760560230097e+00
1.261000000000000000e+04 2.647388072609410159e+01 5.145277516917245997e+00
1.264000000000000000e+04 2.642779461987591461e+01 5.140797080208079350e+00
1.267000000000000000e+04 3.515095066441973870e+01 5.928823716760327045e+00
1.270000000000000000e+04 3.009481635623761875e+01 5.485874256327574194e+00
1.273000000000000000e+04 4.190175336709399545e+01 6.473156368194267429e+00
1.276000000000000000e+04 4.402442191736321320e+01 6.635090196626057590e+00
1.279000000000000000e+04 4.363190267016754120e+01 6.605444925980954451e+00
1.282000000000000000e+04 4.306920178638941366e+01 6.562712989792363061e+00
1.285000000000000000e+04 5.403092525773050880e+01 7.350573124439380379e+00
1.288000000000000000e+04 5.388982936251477440e+01 7.340969238630194127e+00
1.291000000000000000e+04 5.859001964544118835e+01 7.654411776579647331e+00
1.294000000000000000e+04 5.446686064565554375e+01 7.380166708527358566e+00
1.297000000000000000e+04 6.345356079239230240e+01 7.965774337275209227e+00
1.300000000000000000e+04 6.683755921705329683e+01 8.175424100134090821e+00
1.303000000000000000e+04 5.858468402315401136e+01 7.654063236161170458e+00
1.306000000000000000e+04 7.119399327655042953e+01 8.437653303884346201e+00
1.309000000000000000e+04 7.112058107440432764e+01 8.433301908173591599e+00
1.312000000000000000e+04 6.761749045573240835e+01 8.222985495288947178e+00
1.315000000000000000e+04 6.083220910064191145e+01 7.799500567385190486e+00
1.318000000000000000e+04 7.334513585219225718e+01 8.564177476686962720e+00
1.321000000000000000e+04 5.851547673408833106e+01 7.649540949239263199e+00
1.324000000000000000e+04 5.349860720235638212e+01 7.314274208857389326e+00
1.327000000000000000e+04 6.245184086144253399e+01 7.902647712092607968e+00
1.330000000000000000e+04 5.972298520950170797e+01 7.728064777775980332e+00
1.333000000000000000e+04 5.657703857411996751e+01 7.521770973256229453e+00
1.336000000000000000e+04 5.564927699189464505e+01 7.459844300780991588e+00
1.339000000000000000e+04 4.873255045450958534e+01 6.980870322138177819e+00
1.342000000000000000e+04 4.011080286704587650e+01 6.333308998228798892e+00
1.345000000000000000e+04 3.872016042265131119e+01 6.222552564876516534e+00
1.348000000000000000e+04 3.425547922239898213e+01 5.852818058200594642e+00
1.351000000000000000e+04 3.131402230788760832e+01 5.595893343147956500e+00
1.354000000000000000e+04 2.775826111521034179e+01 5.268610928433636431e+00
1.357000000000000000e+04 2.566850992440435775e+01 5.066409964107164043e+00
1.360000000000000000e+04 2.122252243535132621e+01 4.606790904235976924e+00
1.363000000000000000e+04 2.135596228327256441e+01 4.621251159942787901e+00
1.366000000000000000e+04 1.636462179139272877e+01 4.045320975076356795e+00
1.369000000000000000e+04 1.603685923142635517e+01 4.004604753458991695e+00
1.372000000000000000e+04 1.497318277903302075e+01 3.869519709089620285e+00
1.375000000000000000e+04 1.361062598366308229e+01 3.689258188804774186e+00
1.378000000000000000e+04 1.201705364608464777e+01 3.466562223022204403e+00
1.381000000000000000e+04 1.135332706206522957e+01 3.369469848813790858e+00
1.384000000000000000e+04 8.282564517303091733e+00 2.877944495174132200e+00
1.387000000000000000e+04 8.318208441961562727e+00 2.884130448152711690e+00
1.390000000000000000e+04 7.739068483998881476e+00 2.781918130355183649e+00
1.393000000000000000e+04 5.323047099719408592e+00 2.307172967013832121e+00
1.396000000000000000e+04 4.925921132216046772e+00 2.219441626224047948e+00
1.399000000000000000e+04 7.354848097519979255e+00 2.711982318806665848e+00
1.402000000000000000e+04 6.125028322048942542e+00 2.474879456064262850e+00
1.405000000000000000e+04 5.901755228349636617e+00 2.429352841468204183e+00
1.408000000000000000e+04 6.577349849858411091e+00 2.564634447608159729e+00
1.411000000000000000e+04 4.409931908865672767e+00 2.099983787762579990e+00
1.414000000000000000e+04 4.321585339493646316e+00 2.078842307510035070e+00
1.417000000000000000e+04 6.210351932350224757e+00 2.492057770668694605e+00
1.420000000000000000e+04 4.190208433246443320e+00 2.046999861564832379e+00
1.423000000000000000e+04 4.126349342537677600e+00 2.031341759167490935e+00
1.426000000000000000e+04 4.100466975327557329e+00 2.024960981186441966e+00
1.429000000000000000e+04 3.054595733980268957e+00 1.747740179197202259e+00
1.432000000000000000e+04 3.043823380485536134e+00 1.744655662440453003e+00
1.435000000000000000e+04 6.029319349502011427e+00 2.455467236495329608e+00
1.438000000000000000e+04 4.017580643696878617e+00 2.004390342148175019e+00
1.441000000000000000e+04 4.014504216785971025e+00 2.003622773075303787e+00
1.444000000000000000e+04 4.010217645951591692e+00 2.002552782313512747e+00
1.447000000000000000e+04 4.006715769847827069e+00 2.001678238340974580e+00
1.450000000000000000e+04 4.004228414962338611e+00 2.001056824521067590e+00
1.453000000000000000e+04 6.003107263823054041e+00 2.450123928258130857e+00
1.456000000000000000e+04 3.002162088285443176e+00 1.732674836282169561e+00
1.459000000000000000e+04 3.001365885880213913e+00 1.732445059988978020e+00
1.462000000000000000e+04 5.000781937792266874e+00 2.236242817270134076e+00
1.465000000000000000e+04 5.000499506098897484e+00 2.236179667669594195e+00
1.468000000000000000e+04 4.000376084303172597e+00 2.000094018865906431e+00
1.471000000000000000e+04 5.000209553077802127e+00 2.236114834501529369e+00
1.474000000000000000e+04 3.000116345627365622e+00 1.732084393332889993e+00
1.477000000000000000e+04 4.000087346261155474e+00 2.000021836446081114e+00
1.480000000000000000e+04 5.000041814002868179e+00 2.236077327375524337e+00
1.483000000000000000e+04 4.000035023897440922e+00 2.000008755955193340e+00
1.486000000000000000e+04 4.000017762848898428e+00 2.000004440707294773e+00
1.489000000000000000e+04 5.000008697828882909e+00 2.236069922392607712e+00
1.492000000000000000e+04 4.000005978564794340e+00 2.000001494640640143e+00
1.495000000000000000e+04 4.000004301095668069e+00 2.000001075273627915e+00
1.498000000000000000e+04 6.000001968624238735e+00 2.449490144626885080e+00
1.501000000000000000e+04 4.000001304783485701e+00 2.000000326195845002e+00
1.504000000000000000e+04 4.000000676925454357e+00 2.000000169231356484e+00
1.507000000000000000e+04 5.000000398729777196e+00 2.236068066658476461e+00
1.510000000000000000e+04 4.000000194663009268e+00 2.000000048665751873e+00
1.513000000000000000e+04 3.000000115694128944e+00 1.732050840966895322e+00
1.516000000000000000e+04 6.000000066131374155e+00 2.449489756282188235e+00
1.519000000000000000e+04 4.000000042951537438e+00 2.000000010737884359e+00
1.522000000000000000e+04 4.000000016347793341e+00 2.000000004086948113e+00
1.525000000000000000e+04 3.000000011725127980e+00 1.732050810953630116e+00
1.528000000000000000e+04 4.000000005053738761e+00 2.000000001263434690e+00
1.531000000000000000e+04 3.000000002494255469e+00 1.732050808288906785e+00
1.534000000000000000e+04 5.000000001461630816e+00 2.236067977826620368e+00
1.537000000000000000e+04 6.000000000788251242e+00 2.449489742944079396e+00
1.540000000000000000e+04 3.000000000429047464e+00 1.732050807692732564e+00
1.543000000000000000e+04 3.000000000229988473e+00 1.732050807635269196e+00
1.546000000000000000e+04 6.000000000101302966e+00 2.449489742803856451e+00
1.549000000000000000e+04 6.000000000054173555e+00 2.449489742794236147e+00
1.552000000000000000e+04 6.000000000026601832e+00 2.449489742788608204e+00
1.555000000000000000e+04 4.000000000011663559e+00 2.000000000002915890e+00
1.558000000000000000e+04 4.000000000007153389e+00 2.000000000001788347e+00
1.561000000000000000e+04 4.000000000002709832e+00 2.000000000000677236e+00
1.564000000000000000e+04 6.000000000001476153e+00 2.449489742783479418e+00
1.567000000000000000e+04 3.000000000000590195e+00 1.732050807569047723e+00
1.570000000000000000e+04 6.000000000000345501e+00 2.449489742783248492e+00
1.573000000000000000e+04 4.000000000000141220e+00 2.000000000000035083e+00
1.576000000000000000e+04 3.000000000000054179e+00 1.732050807568892958e+00
1.579000000000000000e+04 3.000000000000027534e+00 1.732050807568885187e+00
1.582000000000000000e+04 4.000000000000013323e+00 2.000000000000003109e+00
1.585000000000000000e+04 6.000000000000005329e+00 2.449489742783179214e+00
1.588000000000000000e+04 5.000000000000002665e+00 2.236067977499790249e+00
1.591000000000000000e+04 3.000000000000001332e+00 1.732050807568877637e+00
1.594000000000000000e+04 5.000000000000000888e+00 2.236067977499789805e+00
1.597000000000000000e+04 3.000000000000000000e+00 1.732050807568877193e+00
```

Comment: If it might be of some use, I am getting excellent fits of the individual peaks to a Logistic peak equation "y = 4.0 * a * exp(-1.0 * (x - b) / c) / pow(1.0 + exp(-1.0 * (x - b) / c), 2.0)"

Answer (score 0):

Hm, I'm not sure why your fit with weighting by uncertainties is causing `g2_center` to get stuck at its lower bound.  I don't get that actually.

But: depending on the meaning of your `err` array, I would think you would want to use:

```
weight = 1./err
```

That is, you want to have the fit minimize

```
Sum { [ (data-fit)/err ]**2 }
```

so you want to tell the function generating the residual to return

```
(data-fit) * weight  = (data-fit)/err
```

and let the fit do the sum-of-squares.

When I use `weight=1./err` for your fit, I get a reduced chi-square value of ~0.3, which I would say is pretty close to 1.0.  Using your value gives reduced chi-square of ~2.e-5.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Are you sure that's how the error gets assigned in lmfit? Do they do the weighting before or after squaring? Also, any idea (leaving aside the fact that the fit is wrong) why doesn't it prints the place where it gets stuck at least (which is not 9979.839872555114)?

Comment: Yes, I am sure.  Giving `weights` to `Model.fit` changes the array to minimize from `(data-fit)` to `(data-fit)*weights`.  As I said, I don't know why your fit got a bad result -- you did not provide a full and complete script to reproduce the problem.  But, having a Parameter (your mu_2) stuck at (or, very strangely, exceeding!) a boundary  could suggest that is where the problem lies.

Comment: Please note, that there is also `scale_covar` parameter of `Model.fit` function. As the documentation says: "Whether to automatically scale the covariance matrix when calculating uncertainties (default is True)."